# В коде множество элементов одни, а в отладчике они перемешаны

Tags: python, visual-studio

У меня есть множество элементов

```
x = {1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 15, 18, 20}
y = {3.60, 3.20, 2.57, 1.95, 1.45, 1.09, 0.9, 0.6, 0.3, 0.1}
```

Но когда я смотрю через отладчик Visual Studio, то там некоторые элементы идут в другом порядке(на следующем шаге после инициализации y):

y={0.9, 1.95, 2.57, 3.2, 3.6, 1.45, 1.09, 0.6, 0.3, 0.1}

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Множество не сохраняет порядок элементов, оно для другого нужно.

Если вам нужен контейнер, который сохраняет порядок элементов, то используйте список.

Множество же обеспечивает работу с уникальными элементами, поэтому для него вообще сложно придумать какое-то естественное поведение в терминах порядка элементов. Например, вы создаёте множество и последовательно начинаете добавлять в него элементы. Если встречаются повторяющиеся элементы, то они схлопываются с теми своими дублями, которые уже содержатся в множестве. Что в этом случае должно считаться порядком элементов? Тот порядок в котором они появились в множестве в первый раз? Тот порядок в котором они появились в последний раз?

Кроме того, для множества самые частые сценарии использования - это проверка на вхождение (в том числе неявно при добавлении нового элемента) и поиск пересечений с другими множествами. Именно под эти сценарии множества максимально оптимизированы. Если добавить к этому какие-то требования по сохранению порядка, то эти оптимизации станут невозможными и множества потеряют своё ключевое преимущество.